# How can I get all Auth Users on Webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm making an administrative tool, and I need to list all my auth users on webapp2. The problem is that the User model of auth models doesn't have the all() method.

So, how can I get all users on webapp2?

Answer (score 1):

Edited to show a more complete example:

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User
class UserHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        users = User.query().fetch()
        self.render_response('templates/users.html', locals())
```

Inside the template, `users.html`, you can loop through the `users` variable.

My `BaseHandler` includes the method `render_response()` to render a template.

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanation to this answer?